# Reverse lookup of a sub-string in a dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, categories

I am struggling to find a "pythonic" way to make this logic work:

I have a dataframe of payment transactions with a column of strings( "beneficiary"):

| index | beneficiary |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | REWE SAGT DANKE. ... |
| 13 | NaN |
| 14 | OBI BAU- U. HEIMWER//BERLIN/DE / OBI SAGT DANKE |
| 15 | NETFLIX INTERNATIONAL B.V. |

I need to create another column in my dataframe which would be the category that every line belongs to.

| index | beneficiary | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | REWE SAGT DANKE. ... | Groceries |
| 14 | OBI BAU- U. HEIMWER//BERLIN/DE / OBI SAGT DANKE | Groceries |
| 15 | NETFLIX INTERNATIONAL B.V. | Entertainment |

I am thinking to make a dictionary like this below and somehow reverse look-up the sub-string values from the categories dict with the column above:

```
categories = {"Groceries": ["EDEKA", "REWE", "OBI"],
            "Entertainment": ["NETFLIX"]}
```

The logic is: if sub-string "REWE" is in df['beneficiary'] then df['category'] equals the key of the dict element where the sub-string is.

I am open to other mapping logic.

Comment: How many such rules are there, and how long are beneficiary names? If these numbers get big, a trie-based algorithm might be the most asymptotically efficient. If these numbers are small, it might be better to just scan each beneficiary for each keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex, for this you need to rework your dictionary to have the matched strings as key and categories as values:

```py
categories = {"Groceries": ["EDEKA", "REWE", "OBI"],
              "Entertainment": ["NETFLIX"]}

cat_sub = {v:k for k,l in categories.items() for v in l}
regex = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(fr'\b{c}\b' for c in cat_sub)
# regex looks like this: (\bEDEKA\b|\bREWE\b|\bOBI\b|\bNETFLIX\b)

df['category'] = df['beneficiary'].str.extract(regex, expand=False).map(cat_sub)
```

*NB. I used word boundaries (`\b`) to ensure matching full words, use `regex = r'(%s)' % '|'.join(cat_sub)`  if you don't want this behaviour*

output:

```
   index                                       beneficiary       category
0      12                             REWE SAGT DANKE. ...      Groceries
1      13                                              NaN            NaN
2      14  OBI BAU- U. HEIMWER//BERLIN/DE / OBI SAGT DANKE      Groceries
3      15                       NETFLIX INTERNATIONAL B.V.  Entertainment
```

*NB. if needed to drop the NaNs, use `dropna`*

Answer (score 2):

Try reversing your dictionary to map each word to a category and applying this to each word in "beneficiary":

```py
word_cat = {w: k for k,v in categories.items() for w in v}
df["category"] = df["beneficiary"].str.split(expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.map(word_cat)).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
df = df.dropna()

>>> df
   index                                    beneficiary       category
0     12                               REWE SAGT DANKE.      Groceries
2     14  OBI BAU-U. HEIMWER//BERLIN/DE /OBI SAGT DANKE      Groceries
3     15                     NETFLIX INTERNATIONAL B.V.  Entertainment
```